# Exception handling with Realbrowserlocusts

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, locust

In using realbrowserlocusts class it appears that I'm limited in any exception handling.
The only reference that partially works is: self.client.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located ....

In a failed condition where the element is not found the script simply starts over again. With the script I'm working with I need to maintain a solid session state; I need to throw and exception(report an error), log the user out and then let the script start over again. I've been testing out the behavior with the locust.py script that Nick B. created with several approaches to "try, except" and they work running without realbrowserlocusts (selenium only) but with it the execution just stops.
Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

In its current format I've been able to run 3x the amount of a browser-based load per/agent/slave than our commercial tool. My goal is to replace it with a locust/selenium approach.

Answer (score 0):

`locust-plugins`'s WebdriverUser has a little bit better exception handling I think. A failure to find an element will log a failed request and if you use RescheduleTaskOnFail (as in the the example) it will restart the task when that happens.

https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/webdriver_ex.py